# Can we use Operator precedence parsing with this grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, compilers, parsers

This Grammar:

A-->Bbab|aa

B-->b

I think we can't because basically there is no relation between terminals? like no relation between a and b! or am i missing something? and the language of this grammar has only 2 members !

can we using Operator precedence parsing with this grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an operator grammar since no right-hand side has two consecutive non-terminals. So we then attempt to construct the precedence relations:

$$b \gtrdot b \\
b \doteq a \\
a \doteq b \\
a \doteq a
$$

There is no multiple entry, so an operator precedence parser is possible.